# NUnit: Assert.Multiple for methods that contain Assume.That

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, assert

I'm testing a web page that contains, let's say, three different modules. In my test framework each page module is represented by its own test class: `Module1Tests`, `Module2Tests`, `Module3Tests`. Besides, to satisfy specific conditions for each module, I use `Assume.That` in each of test classes.
With this setup everything works fine if I'm just testing separate modules.
But, when I create a test class for the whole page and use `Assert.Multiple` like this:

```
public class HomePageTests
    {
        public Module1Tests Module1Tests { get; } = new Module1Tests();

        public Module2Tests Module2Tests { get; } = new Module2Tests();

        public Module3Tests Module3Tests { get; } = new Module3Tests();

[Test]
public void HomePage()
{
    Assert.Multiple(() =>
    {
        Module1Tests.Module1TestMethod();
        Module2Tests.Module2TestMethod();
        Module3Tests.Module3TestMethod();
    });
}
```

I get error message that I cannot use methods with `Assume.That` within `Assert.Multiple` blocks.

I also tried calling module test methods without `Assert.Multiple` block, but the whole page test stops executing at the first failure.

Is there a way to resolve this? Basically I just want to have a test for the page that would pass if all underlying module tests pass.

Comment: Yes, that's intentional. I hope there must be some other way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, and as the message indicates, you cannot use assumptions within a multiple assert block. If you look at the list of excluded items in note 6 on the Assumptions page of the docs, you will see that they are all items intended to terminate execution of the test immediately.

Assert.Fail as well as failed assertions are also intended to terminate the test immediately, of course. Multiple assertions make an exception to that... the failure is recorded but the test is not terminated until all nested Assert.Multiple blocks end.

I considered making some exceptions for each of the items on the list, which would have required defining new behavior for each of them. It was not clear what the best alternative behavior would be so I decided to wait for user feedback. This SO question is actually the first feedback I've seen anywhere, so thanks!

In common use, assumptions are placed ahead of all the assertions, sometimes even in the SetUp method. Their meaning in that case is basically: "If this assumption fails, then it doesn't make sense to run the test." Occasionally, they are placed after a few assertions, meaning "If this fails, it doesn't make sense to run any more of the test."

If I understand you correctly, you would like a failed assumption to mean that we should skip all the following assertions in one of your module tests, but continue with any other module tests. But the notion of a module test within a test case is not something that exists in NUnit, at least today. The structuring available to you in NUnit is represented by the hierarchy:
  * Namespace (possibly nested)
    * Fixture
      * Test Case
        * Multiple Assert block (possibly nested)
          * Assertions

If your module tests use a Multiple Assert block themselves, then we could consider mapping the behavior of Assume within a multiple assert block to mean "It makes no sense to run any more of the test code within this block." If you want that, you will need to file a feature request on github. I can tell you up front it's not a trivial change, so it's not guaranteed we would do it, but it might be worth doing some analysis to see how it could work out. Basically, we'd like to give you what you need without confusing other users. :-)

With current capabilities, I see two choices for a workaround:

1. Make each module test a separate test method within a fixture that essentially replaces the current test method. Place the Order attribute on each test if order of execution is important to you. In other words, your existing fixture with n tests would become n separate fixtures. I don't know if this is possible for you since I haven't seen your code, but it is one way to make use of the existing facilities of NUnit for structuring tests.
2. Encapsulate your module tests as a set of classes rather than a set of methods. Run all your assumptions with one method and all your assertions with another method. Call all the assumptions up front, before your Assert.Multiple block. If you don't want failed assumptions to stop the entire test, then you'll have to return a bool from the assumptions entry and remember whether to run each module.
3. Probably the easiest: Make your assumptions into conditions within each module test method. If the assumptions fail, then don't run the tests.

What I really wish I could offer as an alternative for structuring is nested fixtures. In many ways, that would fit what you are trying to do better than the other options. Unfortunately, even though NUnit allows nesting fixtures syntactically, the nesting is ignored entirely when the tests are run. We have an outstanding feature request to change that, but it's fairly futuristic.

2. Replac

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, @Charlie!
Suggestion 1 was the first I tried even before posting my question here. I had a page test class with three `[Test]` blocks, each block representing a method calling module test method from module test classes. Actually it works, but the problem is that I use parameterized test methods for modules (with `[Values]` and `[ValueSource]` attributes) and repeating the same parameter blocks for each module doesn't seem elegant to me. I tried parametrization at a fixture level, but I cannot use `[ValueSource]` attribute there.

Comment: Suggestion 3 looks good, but how do I don't run the test if condition is not satisfied? For example, I use `if` to check for a Boolean condition and if it's not true, what should I do to skip the test? Calling `Assert.Inconclusive` is not allowed for the same reason.

Comment: I'm assuming you would return from your module test, passing control back to the test method itself, which would then call the next module test.

Answer (score 0):

3. Use the Assert Multiple and write a test with 9 asserts. You are free to choose which asserts you will use, but try to use as much as possible different asserts.